# What happens to the prototype when a function redefines itself?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I saw the following code in the [JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) book by Stoyan Stefanov (edited to remove extra fat):

```
function Universe() {
    var instance = this;
    Universe = function() {
        return instance;
    }
}

Universe.prototype.nothing = true;
var uni = new Universe();
Universe.prototype.everything = true;
var uni2 = new Universe();

uni.nothing;     // true
uni2.nothing;    // true, but I was expecting undefined
uni.everything;  // undefined
uni2.everything; // undefined, but I was expecting true
```

I was expecting `nothing` to be assigned to the original function's prototype, and `everything` to be assigned to the closure's prototype (since the second assignment happens after redefinition). However, the output shows that something odd is going on, and the book really doesn't explain it. I also noticed that:

1. `Universe.prototype` does point to a different object after the function is redefined, as I expected.
2. Further instances created after the redefinition still get the original prototype object as their `__proto__`. That's what I don't understand.

Could anyone explain, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uni` and `uni2` are the same object because the value of `instance` is returned in both versions of the `Universe` function.

Here is the same code but without `instance` returned from the redefined `Universe`: http://jsfiddle.net/nmaBn/

Comment: Of course! How could I miss that! I focused on the prototype and the redefinition, and forgot about the return value (which is what the example is all about, actually).

Comment: @bfavaretto I missed it to, had to break out jsFiddle... But, I think you identified some real issues with this implementation of the singleton pattern: the prototype chain gets swapped and, as someone pointed out in a comment, the `instanceof` operator fails. Another potential problem occurs if a reference to the original `Universe` function is stored somewhwere. These are shown in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmaBn/9/). A couple of changes address them, but they add complexity: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmaBn/10/)

Comment: I guess the bottom line is (and due credit must be given to that book for mentioning that): the simplest way to create a singleton in js is to just use an object literal.

Answer (score 5):

It's  a singleton pattern. The first time Universe is created the Universe symbol is redefined. (It still exists in a sort of limbo, though: the instance has some reference to it. `__proto__` in non-strict mode for instance. )

The new Universe symbol *isn't* actually a constructor, it just returns the first created instance. The new keyword in the second call creates a new instance with the second Universe as prototype, but the new function just ignores it and returns the stored first instance instead.

Comment: Thank you, as I commented above I was so focused on other aspects of the code and missed the essential "detail" of what was being returned. D'oh!